# Where to find log file for booting information

Tags: 10.10, boot, log

There are two very quick screens of errors shown after I choose Ubuntu in the screen of Grub and before the scrren of Ubuntu icon. I was wondering where to find the log file of the start information/errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The boot log is located at `/var/log/boot.log`

If that does not have the information you're looking for, then try the command `dmesg` in the terminal.  That should have the detail you may not get in the log file.

Comment: Thanks! But I am sure what I saw during boot is not logged there.

Comment: Update the answer, give that at a try.