# How can I tell if my system was booted as EFI/UEFI or BIOS?

Tags: boot, uefi, bios

How do I determine whether a particular running Ubuntu system was booted using EFI/UEFI, or BIOS?

Comment: Interesting question. Not an exact dupe but try the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26049/where-to-find-log-file-for-booting-information), to a similar question.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/how-to-know-if-im-booting-using-uefi

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The easiest way is to check to see if `/sys/firmware/efi` exists.  It does not appear if you booted using traditional BIOS.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
```

Comment: Tested on QEMU 2.0.0, OVFM and Ubuntu 14.04:  https://github.com/cirosantilli/runlinux/tree/9f03d08838705082c0e316dcff6a199bd4edac0c

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04, and Fedora 24

Comment: nitpick, that expression is POSIX so should work in a variety of shells, not just `bash`

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 22):

> #### Deprecated
>
> The answer below is a method that may not always work.
>  Instead use [Colin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162896/58612) based on `/sys/firmware/efi`.

---

It's very easy to tell if a system was booted in EFI (or not, in which case it *must* be BIOS):

Just use `dmesg | grep "EFI v"`

- This will return a line like this, if the system was booted off of EFI:

  ```
  [ 0.000000] EFI v2.00 by American Megatrends
  ```
- Or return nothing if it was not, in which case it was booted off of BIOS

#### Example of bash script usage based on *grep's* exit code:

```
...
dmesg | grep -q "EFI v"    # -q tell grep to output nothing
if [ $? -eq 0 ]      # check exit code; if 0 EFI, else BIOS
then
    echo "You are using EFI boot."
  else
    echo "You are using BIOS boot"
fi
...
```

> Source: For how to determine if an EFI system is using legacy-BIOS emulation or not, as well as more information on testing for EFI and EFI compatibility, along with the strings for a number of EFI vendors/versions, please see [this page from the Ubuntu Developer Summit for Precise](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Testing/UDS-P-UEFI).

Comment: I'd simplify that to `if dmesg | grep -Fq "EFI v"; then ...`. No point in running the `[` command in addition, just to test for success/failure. `$?` is mainly useful for checking for specific errors.

Comment: This is brittle, as there is no guarantee that the string searched for is generated by the desired feature.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: The Ubuntu Developer Summit folks seem to think it's part of the specification...can you provide a source or reference for your contention?

Comment: @izx, any script can happen to write "EFI v" as part of something else.  If that happens on a BIOS machine, this would be a false positive.

Comment: Best not to grep for text in the kernel log, it is subject to change.  Best to look at /sys/firmware/efi

Comment: I'd like to mention however that this is a great way to get the EFI version!

Comment: Go figure ... `ls: cannot access '/etc/firmware': No such file or directory` however `[0.000000] efi: EFI v2.60 by American Megatrends`. This is on an Arch.

Comment: @Vorac, I believe the accepted approach is to look in `/sys/firmware/efi`, **_not_** `/etc/firmware`.  Did you check to see if the former exists?

Answer (score -1):

Python code to check if system is booted with UEFI or ROM BIOS:

```
import os,sys
def main():
    if(os.path.exists("/sys/firmware/efi")):
        print"\n\n System is booted with uefi!"
    else:
        print"\n\n System is booted with rom bios"
main()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Python2.mumble only?