# How can I stop Ubuntu 14.04 from crashing ~10% of the time when I attempt suspend?

Tags: 14.04, boot, suspend, wakeup

I've been trying to solve this on and off for a year, and have read, and tried, most of the solutions I've seen online, and it still crashes regularly, but not every time, on attempted standbys. Resumes never fail, and it never crashes any other way, eg shutdowns haven't failed.

**The crash looks like this:**

1. I hit the <kbd>suspend</kbd> button on the system menu
2. Immediately, with no delay, the screen changes to the login screen, but completely frozen

**Nothing works:**

- Mouse
- Keyboard
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Sysrq</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd>

I just hold the power button until it quietly dies :(

---

It is a custom-built computer, here's some details that might be important:

- Intel i7-4790k
- Asus Z97-A ATX
- No dedicated graphics card, using Intel iGPU

  *(I know Nvidia cards had a similar bug)*
- 32GB RAM
- 16 GB SWAP partition
- Boot partition - 250MB, 150MB unused (Don't know if this could matter)

---

Here are some excerpts from `/var/log/kern.log` :

A **successful** standby attempt:

```
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.263819] wlan0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (reason=3)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.279076] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284049] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284051] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284052] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284053] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284054] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284055] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  6 23:00:43 Helios kernel: [130991.284055] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov  6 23:00:44 Helios kernel: [130992.610450] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Nov  6 23:00:44 Helios kernel: [130992.646136] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
```

An **un-successful** attempt:

```
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.654635] wlan0: deauthenticating from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (reason=3)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.669411] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674029] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674031] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674032] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674033] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674033] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674034] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Nov 12 14:49:10 Helios kernel: [105446.674035] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Notice, it's missing the `PM:syncing filesystems...` and the following line.

---

Here's a weird thing, when I turn the computer back on, out of standby, I get some boot logs that, to *me* look like logs for while it's *suspending*, not resuming. But maybe it's nothing:

```
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.646268] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.648070] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.649308] PM: Entering mem sleep
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.649443] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.649616] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.649632] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.649694] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.650499] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.673064] serial 00:0a: disabled
Nov  7 08:46:39 Helios kernel: [130992.673066] serial 00:0a: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
# Around 110 more lines of wake-up logs
```

Help?

Comment: A couple of questions: **1)** If you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, does using Legacy mode instead solve the issue? **2)** Do you still experience the problem with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Also, not at all related, but why did you create a separate `/boot` partition?

Comment: @AndroidDev **1)** how could I check? It's all new hardware, and my sole OS is ubunutu 14.04 installed from a thumb drive onto a blank-slate new computer that I built **2)** i've considered upgrading, but haven't yet, so, not sure **3)** i think the `/boot` partition was a default option when installing, and I didn't know what I was doing. I regret having such a small partition now, as it frequently fills up and I start having issues updating things

Comment: I'd turn off Freeze suspend and use suspend to ram instead. Also make sure hybrid suspend isn't being used sometimes through some bug because 16GB Swap isn't enough for 32GB RAM.

Comment: @Josh.F **1)** http://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios **2)** Try a live USB then **3)** Yeah, I would always recommend having only one partition for `/` and `/boot`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that sounds like what I want; so it just saves state to RAM instead of swap, and consumes a bit more electricity? Any advice/link that could walk me through it?

Comment: I can't search Ask Ubuntu now because I'm on my phone. But just search on "suspend" and let me know later if you can't find any instructions and I'll search.

Comment: To debug issues occurring during suspension or after wake-up, please [edit] your question and include the output of `sudo dmesg` and the content of `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` after a (potentially unsuccessful) suspend/wake-up cycle. Thanks.