# Ubuntu server does not boot after initial install, but Ubuntu desktop does

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I have a weird problem. With UEFI disabled, when I install Ubuntu Server 18.04 on my HP Probook 4530s, I get the following error:

```
BootDevice Not Found

Please install an operating system on your hard disk.

Hard Disk - (3FO)

...
```

I've tested my new hard disk, and it's fine. However, when I install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04, it works perfectly.

I even ran boot-repair, which generated [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vc7wjvgrZJ/) pastebin.

**Question:** How do I get Ubuntu Server running on my machine?

---

Additional details:

- I only need Ubuntu server alone on this laptop
- There's only a single 1 TB HDD on this device, although you can tell that from the pastebin.

Things I've tried:

- Boot repair
- Switching from AHCI to IDE in SATA settings
- Turing UEFI on and reinstalling

Nothing changes the end result.

Comment: I can't help much with that, but to give you some direction: this sounds like Server is getting installed via pre-UEFI MBR way, whereas desktop gets installed GPT-way that UEFI is using. If your UEFI has a compatibility mode to boot from MBR, you could try it to figure out if that's the reason. Also: if this turns out to be true, this is a bug in Server installer, and better to be reported on launchpad.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I'm installing with UEFI disabled, though. So it shouldn't really be a problem, should it?

Comment: If I was you, I'd double check that it works as you expect. For example that Ubuntu Desktop system that was installed and ran while UEFI is disabled [indeed does not use it](https://askubuntu.com/q/162564/266507#how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios). You know, different things could happen, e.g. "disabling UEFI" might not do what you'd expect it to, UEFI might be buggy, etc… When something does not work, any plausible explanation is worth checking, and UEFI firmwares are far from perfect.