# Dual boot with Windows 10, no boot menu showing, goes straight to ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10, for some reason it didn't recognize the Windows EFI (which is in a SDD, Ubuntu doesn't even recognize the SDD). The thing is, I can run both OS fine, but when I start my PC it goes straight to Ubuntu, if I want to run Windows I have to press F12. I there a way to go to the boot menu and choose with OS I want to open?

Edit: I just want to be greeted with this when I turn on my PC
([UEFI Boot Menu on Dell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q47SK.png))

Comment: Are drives all gpt partitioned? Is Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation All systems need to be in same boot mode. And if UEFI best to use gpt, even though Ubuntu will let you use the old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Grub only boots working Windows, so when Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, you still have to f12 boot into Windows.

Comment: Windows fast start up is off, I remember unchecking that when I installed Ubuntu. How do I know if all drives are gpt partitioned?

Comment: Post this above in question: `sudo parted -l` Should be MBR(msdos) or gpt.

Comment: @oldfred As far as I can tell the partitions are in gpt (it said `Partition Table: gpt`)

Comment: If both systems are UEFI, Windows fast start up is off, Drives are AHCI, SSD and UEFI have firmware updates, this should add Windows to grub menu. `sudo update-grub`. Note that Windows updates will turn fast start up back on, then grub will not boot Windows. But you can directly boot from UEFI to turn it back off.

Comment: @oldfred it didn work. I turn on my computer and get is a GNU GRUB version 2.something, but no way to get to windows. So far only by pressing F12 I can open windows, by the BOOT MENU (kinda like the picture I posted in the edit)

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was because I had installed Ubuntu using bios mode but Windows using efi mode.

This explains how you can check if ubuntu is in efi mode: [How can I tell if my system was booted as EFI/UEFI or BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios)

There was a way to convert an existing ubuntu install from bios mode to efi (which is what I did) but I'm having trouble finding it now.

Edit:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  << Scroll down to "converting ubuntu into uefi mode"

Comment: According to this I installed Ubuntu in EFI mode. I remember I had to create an EFI especially for Ubuntu, could it be because of that?