# Ubuntu does not recognise SSD nor Windows EFI

Tags: partitioning, grub2, windows-10

Back again with the same problem as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236266/dual-boot-with-windows-10-no-boot-menu-showing-goes-straight-to-ubuntu) but I managed to identify the real problem.

My computer has a 1TB HHD and 256GB SSD. When I first installed Ubuntu it didn't found my SSD where the Windows EFI is, so being a newbie I created an EFI partition for Ubuntu and have been working like this for a few months, when I want to use Ubuntu I just start my computer and wait for the grub, when I want to use Windows I start my computer, press F12 and select Windows Boot Manager.

Now, due to preference, I want to use Windows most of the time, but it will be tiring having to press F12 all the time.

So my question is, is there a way to read the SSD or to include the Windows Boot Manager to the grub without reinstalling Ubuntu?

PS: I have run `sudo os-prober` and nothing appears.

Comment: You can change the boot order in your BIOS/UEFI settings or with efibootmg on Ubuntu.  Windows not beening seen is another problem, maybe it's hibernated, or in raid, or.... Reread the UEFI initial setup for all the things to check on the Windows side, fix those, and grub should then see and pick up windows for its boot menu.

Comment: Have you tried Boot repair.  It can help you install grub where you really want it.  Then change the grub defaults to "last boot" so that is boots the last one every time. You can also change the BIOS to boot the Windows every time.  If you want Ubuntu then you will need to go to BIOS and change the boot order again.( Agree with @ubfan1.  He beat me by seconds :)

Comment: @ubfan1 I belive I did everything right with windows, I deactivated the hibernation and I make sure to really shut it down.

Comment: @walttheboss i did tried boot repair, and nothing really changed. Maybe i am doing something wrong there?

Comment: Please post the boot-repair link, that gives much info which may help diagnose the problem.  Another possibility, Windows and Ubuntu are installed in different modes.  The common assumption with W10 these days is UEFI, but maybe not if an upgrade from 7.

Comment: I recommend moving Windows above Ubunru in boot sequence in Firmware settings. I mostly use windows too and this is what I have done.

Comment: @ubfan1 http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XXc72WCkw3/ I did it again just to be sure

Comment: I also reread the UEFI setup and apparently I had missed the part to disable the secureboot in windows, I did that now but i am lost at what to do

Comment: Report is not showing SSD at all. Did you update UEFI and SSD firmware? Is Windows fast start up off? Is SSD set as AHCI in UEFI settings? You already show Windows as first in UEFI boot order, so does it not boot first.

Comment: @oldfred Did you update UEFI and SSD firmware? I don't know how to do that. Is Windows fast start up off? Yes, it is off. Is SSD set as AHCI in UEFI settings? Again, don't know how to do that. You already show Windows as first in UEFI boot order, so does it not boot first. I can boot Windows if it is first and when is not by pressing F12 and choosing it.

Comment: Most update UEFI from within Windows. Some update from within Ubuntu. Devices using LVFS for firmware updates
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist  Most let you download an update file from vendor's support site into a FAT32 partition and UEFI will read that directly. My Samsung NVMe SSD had an ISO for update in its support site. Check your manuals. Also check manual for drive settings in UEFI (f2 for most), It should not be RAID nor Intel RST. But you have to install AHCI drivers into Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on#963100