# Boot-Repair: No recommended Repair (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, boot-repair

I was recently trying to add a second GPU to my desktop when I started getting booted into GRUB. No matter which GPU I use now, I boot into it.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on to my USB and installed boot-repair:
I did not get a `Recommended Repair` option, but only an `Apply` option.

I generated a report before clicking `Apply`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FG4nNZ6wqB/

And here is the report after clicking `Apply`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jGfqrkF6q7/

Unfortunately the repair failed as I tried rebooting without the live USB and was put into GRUB once again.

NOTE: I am NOT dual booting Windows.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You do not boot in EFI mode so it cannot repair your EFI installed system. You need to boot your system this way either by disabling the CSM compatibility in your firmware and setting it to boot EFI only if those settings are there. Or on my board I can hit the F12 key to get a menu where it will show my boot options with an EFI in the front of the ones that can boot this way. `This live-session is not in EFI-mode.`

Comment: It looks like sda2 was erased. It shows no UUID and the UEFI boot is trying to boot from an UUID that does not exist? Do you have good backups? Easier to reinstall & restore from backups. If no backups, may be difficult to recover some of your data.

Comment: Hey @HappyTux, I checked and unfortunately `/sys/firmware/efi/` exists, so I'm pretty sure it is booting in EFI mode. (according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios)

Comment: @HappyTux Oh, I see what you meant by `This live-session is not in EFI-mode.`. Didn't notice it at first in the pastebin... I retried and attempted another boot repair: (this time in EFI mode) http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KFTysGhzpR/

Comment: Hey @oldfred, I did `sudo blkid` and I am getting a PARTUUID for `sda2` whereas for `sda3` I am getting a `UUID` as well as a `PARTUUID`. 
I only have whatever auto backups were created as a result of `deja-dup`. Not sure how I can access them given that the partition appears to be deleted though

Comment: Yes it has somehow deleted your partition no wonder it does not boot, there is nothing there to boot. All the files are in place in that latest repair booting of it you show at the paste.ubuntu.

Comment: Dang, so is my only option reinstalling Ubuntu with no data recovery?

Comment: I might try testdisk and its deeper search. But that is normally to restore a missing partition. You have partition, but no data. If it can recover it back to ext4, then fsck may repair it. But fsck will only work if seen as ext4.  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step Also does this show anything different? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`