# Where to find boot log files?

Tags: boot, displaylink

Since updating Kubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04 and my displaylink driver to 5.4 (necessary due to the 5.11 kernel in use on 21.04) my laptop hard freezes (meaning I have to press the power button to shut it down), when I power it up while my usb-c dock is plugged in.

I would like to report this behaviour to display link. Where can I find the related log files?

Please note that I do not want the log file of the latest successful boot, as this does not contain any info (the displaylink adapter is not plugged in). Hence, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26049/where-to-find-log-file-for-booting-information) is not a dublicate.

Comment: All system log-files are normally in `/var/log`. The  boot.log and syslog files are often a good place to start, but look around if others looks interesting. ,.

Comment: `journalctl` with the `-b` / `--boot[=offset]` might be worth a try - you can get a list of boot attempts and their offsets using `journalctl --list-boots`

Comment: @Bruni if you have a question about how to *interpret* the boot log, please ask it separately

Comment: @steeldriver fair point

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @waltinator The comment I had added would significantly alter the question and would therefore not be fair to be included in the same question. I had clearly indicated that when I said steeldiver that he made a fair point, so back off,